# how to compress video on android studio in java

Tags: java, android

i try all classes like SiliCompressor,

but all give this error message:

Unsupported get request. Object with ID '698664617315269' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api}

Comment: Looks like that error is from your Facebook library, not the video compressor library.

Comment: yeah, i think that use that api to compress files?? cause all librarys and classes i found set the same error message